# Glimpse hangs with unresponsive javascript messages when trying to open panel

Tags: asp.net, webforms, glimpse

I have Glimpse installed in a .net 4 webforms site (glimpse 1.8.3, glimpse.webforms 1.8.0). When I turn glimpse on from glimpse.axd the small strip appears as expected at the bottom right of the browser window. As soon as I try to open the full glimpse panel, the browser slows down and starts to generate unresponsive javascript notifications. This behaviour is consistent across Chrome 33, Firefox 27 and IE 11.

The site is running on a macbook pro (osx 10.9.1) in a virtual machine on VMWare Fusion running windows 8.1 and IIS 8.5.

Can anyone make any suggestions as to how I can get glimpse to respond?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue appears to be related to the caching in the websites and Glimpse loading the cache tab first, as detailed in this Glimpse support ticket:

https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/issues/756